# Formatting Text in Legend

Tags: matlab

I have a randomised parameter, is there a way I can make sure that its reflected in my legend.

So that my legend may read "So-and-So distribution with parameter value X". Where X changes each time the code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `s=sprintf('legend%1.0f', X)` and `legend(s)` to make a variable legend which will be updated everytime according to the value of `X`. Obviously you can make any legend in this way(different combinations of letters and numbers)